# Can someone please put an end to "LEAVE APP" misery!

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This question has been asked many times everywhere! and there is no reply / answer that explains how it should work!

According to the documentation at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

A canvas app should redirect user to the

**"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL"**

to get authorization and necessary permissions. And, according to the documentation, this URL will take user to a window with two buttons:

**"Allow" , "Don't Allow".**

And, (again according to the docs) when user hits Don't Allow, it will redirect user to the redirect_uri with an error code!

But in reality, this URL takes user to a window, where it there is:

**"Allow", "Leave App"**

People have been saying use "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?cancel_url", but it is not what it says on the authentication page, and I could not find any documentation about the "login.php" end point, e.g. how to give permission list.

Can someone please put an end to this misery!

Thanks a ton...

Comment: Having the same issue, am experimenting to try to find a work around, but thus far, no joy :(

Answer (score -3):

Someone on the FB developers forum resolved this issue.

Basically, if your redirect_uri is like: "http://apps.facebook.com/your_app/", it shows "leave app". If the url has your own domain (e.g. http://yourdomain.com/fbapp/) , than it shows "Don't Allow"

Comment: Actually, that answer was shown to be bogus.  I've seen the same problem, and the FIRST time you go to the URL, it shows "Don't Allow" and properly redirects, thereafter revisiting the SAME URL WITH SAME PARAMS it shows "Leave App" and redirects to the users profile instead.